# Is there way to enable Offline Files on Windows 10 Home without upgrading to Pro?

Tags: offline-files

I have a laptop that only requires the Offline Files feature in Windows 10 Pro. It is currently is running Windows 10 Home. Is there a way to enable that feature without a full upgrade to Windows 10 Pro?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "a laptop that only requires the Offline Files in Windows 10 Pro"? Is a message telling you something when you attempt to load Offline Files? On a personal computer, what are you trying to accomplish with Offline Files?

Answer (score 1):

While most sources indicate that Home editions of Windows have never supported Offline Files, a Microsoft Support Rep claims that the Sync Center is available in all editions of Windows 10: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files-winpc/windows-10-editions-that-support-sync-center/bf44f17f-f5ae-460f-aba1-841e46a70799?auth=1

They recommend the following steps to enable:

1. Press “Windows+X” and go to “control panel”.
2. Click on “sync center” and click on “manage offline files”.
3. Check whether it is enabled or not. In any case it is not, click Enable Offline Files followed by Ok. You will be asked to restart the computer.

Please follow these steps and report whether or not you are successful.

Comment: The referenced forum thread is full of misinformation. The steps above work for Windows 10 Pro. On Windows 10 Home, clicking on "Manage offline files" results in absolutely nothing. No dialog. No error. Nada.

Answer (score 0):

There are two alternative solutions for this problem.

## Solution 1:

download [SyncToy from Microsoft website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15155), it is old software, but works very well on Winodws 10 home premium, also it can be run in windows console (command prompt).

## Solution 2:

download [free files sync](https://freefilesync.org), it is free, I did not try it but I saw it is recommended in many companies.

I am using the first solution with some extra steps to make it run in windows task scheduler to do sync periodically.